# Selective masking in QGIS for point markers

Tags: qgis-3

According to [the changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#feature-selective-masking) of QGIS 3.12 the selective masking will not only work with labels, it should also be available for point features. However, I can't find the function for point features, only labels. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Oslandia (developer of the feature) blog post on selective masking](https://oslandia.com/en/offre-qgis/selective-masking/) states:

> For marker symbols, a new type of point symbology will be developed
>   that will allow to choose a shape and size. As for labeling, a
>   selection of symbol layers to cut will be possible.

So it seems you have to use a special type of point symbol.

EDIT :

The solution is to add a symbol layer of "Mask" type in your point symbology then you should be able to configure the masking the same way you do for label